# SQL IN (SELECT statement) where the matched SELECT statement is an array, is this possible?

Tags: mysql, arrays, pdo

I have two databases that I'd like to match results against. One of them has a column that stores an array of information to be matched with another table.

```
table1
 ------------------------------------
| collection_id |        items_array |
 ------------------------------------
|          123  | ['item1' ,'item2'] |
 ------------------------------------

table2
 ---------------------
|  user_id |  item_id |
 ---------------------
|        2 |    item1 |
|        1 |    item2 | 
 ---------------------
```

I'd like to make an SQL query that will use the table1.collection_id to get the table1.items_array column, then get each table2.user_id where the table2.item_id is in the table1.items_array array. My expression right now is (in PDO):

```
SELECT
    table2.user_id
FROM table2
WHERE table2.item_id IN (
    SELECT table1.items_array
    FROM table1
    WHERE table1.collection_id = ?
)
```

So the idea is that the IN statement should come out to be the array from items_array column. However, this is not working. I've tried formatting the array in the items_array column differently to see if it is a syntax error. I've tried the following:

```
['item1', 'item2']
['item1','item2']
'item1', 'item2'
```

But none of them seem to get the intended result.

Is it even possible to do what I'm hoping to do or should I seek at storing the information a different way? I'd like to store it as an array because once the array is placed, the user will never have to update or match against the array again, so I don't think there will be a normalization issue.

Comment: That's not how you are supposed to use a relational database.
You should have a table "items" with the id of the item, and its name.
A table "collection" with the id of the collection and its name,
then another table "collections_items" with a collection_id and an item_id where you store the links between collections and items.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query

```
SELECT @items := items_array FROM table1 WHERE collection_id = 123;

SELECT table2.user_id
FROM table2
WHERE table2.item_id IN  ( @items );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Like` instead of IN.

```
with table2 as 
(
select item_id ='item1' union select 'item2' union select 'item3' union select 'item4' 
)
    select item_id from table2 where item_id like  '%' +
    (
    select items_array from
        (
        select items_array = '[''item1'',''item2'']' 
        ) table1
    )
```